# Default fields missing from Account settings/Manage Fields page

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I have spent a couple days trying to hunt down a very nasty bug.  I will have to add at least one other post involving the entity module afterwards, but I feel its too complex to put in one posting.

When I go into the home/administration/configuration/people/account settings, and click on the Manage Fields tab, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in taxonomy_field_extra_fields() (line 161 of /var/www/html/devel/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in taxonomy_field_extra_fields() (line 161 of /var/www/html/devel/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in FieldInfo->getInstances() (line 234 of /var/www/html/devel/modules/field/field.info.class.inc).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in FieldInfo->getInstances() (line 234 of /var/www/html/devel/modules/field/field.info.class.inc).
```

The line numbers may be off because of debugging messages.

There is a distinct chance that this is related to the errors I am getting in the Entity module that causes fatal crashes after a normal cache clear unless I execute drush cc all + a browser cache clear.

This is the list I get:

```
 (null)
 boolean
 date
 date (ISO format)
 date (Unix timestamp)
 decimal 
 file 
 float
 image
 integer
 list (float)
 list (integer)
 list (text)
```

Missing are the following:
     long text,
     long text and summary,
     Term reference,
     Text

I want to assume this must be a glitch in the database, but I don't want to have to rebuild from scratch.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mike